# Correlated bell states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I have a question about terminology. What is the terminology for describing 2 correlated bell states shared by 4 qubits?

Comment: I don't think there is a special terminology for that, although I suspect that this will be some "special" state (well, depending on your correlations, of course). -- Maybe if you would be more specific with your questions and, e.g., would write *formulas*, you might get more precise answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean something like 
$$
|\Psi_{ABCD}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |\Phi_{AB}^+\rangle \otimes |\Phi_{CD}^+ \rangle + |\Phi_{AB}^-\rangle \otimes |\Phi_{CD}^- \rangle \right)
$$
with 
$$
|\Phi_{jk}^{\pm}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |0_j0_k\rangle \pm |1_j1_k\rangle\right)
$$
the Bell states, then
$$
|\Psi_{ABCD}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |0_A0_B0_C0_D\rangle + |1_A1_B1_C1_D\rangle \right)
$$
is a [Greenberger–Horne–Zeilinger state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state) (Wikipedia) or GHZ state of 4 qubits.